# How can l use ffmpeg to extract frames with a certain fps and scaling

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I would like to extract frames at fps=25 and the frames are rescaled to 320x240.

What I have tried:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf scale="320x240" fps=25   frames/c01_%04d.jpeg
```

It returns `fps=25: Invalid argument`

but when I run it with either fps or scale it works.

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf scale="320x240"    frames/c01_%04d.jpeg
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf  fps=25   frames/c01_%04d.jpeg
```

It works. How can I run ffmpeg with scale and fps filters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Join simple filters with a comma:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf "scale=320:240,fps=25" frames/c01_%04d.jpeg
```

#### fps

When using the fps filter to extract frames be aware that if the input frame rate:

- is the same as the fps value then the filter is doing nothing and you can remove it.
- is higher than the fps value then some frames will be omitted to match the fps value. If this is the case then use fps before scale and the process will be faster.
- is lower than the fps value then some frames will be duplicated to match the fps value.

If you want to simply extract **all** frames then remove the fps filter.

#### scale

Consider declaring just width **or** height and using `-1` as the value for the other, such as `320:-1` or `-1:240`. Doing this will allow the filter to automatically choose the proper value while preserving the aspect ratio. This will prevent stretching of the output image aspect ratio.

#### jpeg

[Use `-q:v` or `-qscale:v` to control quality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10234065/1109017).

Comment: If you specify a different ratio h:w when scaling I don't think you'll end up with a stretched image as ffmpeg will by default keep the DAR (display aspect ratio) constant.  But you will end up with a different PAR - ie pixels will not necessarily be square.  Eg 1920x1080 to 1920x540 will keep the aspect ratio but the vertical resolution is halved by having taller pixels.

Comment: @thomasrutter ffmpeg will preserve the DAR by adjusting the SAR. If you want it to stretch add `setsar=1`.

Comment: Yes that's what I was explaining.  But your answer says, `This will prevent stretching of the output image.`.  I wanted to point out that this isn't the case - it wouldn't stretch.

Comment: @thomasrutter Fixed.